# How to prevent the photos I like in Facebook to appear in my friends wall?

Tags: facebook

I like some pages in Facebook very much and I like the posts done by them. However, my friends don't like those pages and get newsfeed about my likes, some of my friends also have complained me about it.

How can I prevent the pages I like appearing in the feed of my posts?

Answer (score 1):

Your friends can change the visibility of your posts; particularly they can choose not to see your "Comments and likes". [Read more about how they can control it](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=188147907920585).

> I found a shortcut. In their news feed, in the upper right corner of the post where you liked something, they can click on the down-arrow. There's an option `Unsubscribe from comments and likes by ThisPerson`.

Alternatively, you can delete the "likes" individually from your timeline. On my Timeline, I see a box "Activity / Recent" which shows the latest likes I have made. I can go in there and click the 'x' to "Remove" the item from the Activity. I think that will stop your friends from seeing it, too.

Comment: @BinitaThapa if this answers your question, don't forget to "accept" it